# How to use for loops to extract the first 3 digits of a string in all columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the first 3 digits of an integer for all columns in a tibble.

The tibble is this:

[image]

I have successfully extracted 3 digits for the first column using;

```
patient_illness$illness_1<- substr(patient_illness$illness_1, 1, 3)
```

Does any one know how can I turn the above code into a loop to extract the first three digits for all 13 columns?

And how can I replace the original columns with the extracted ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `lapply` in `base R`

```
patient_illness[] <- lapply(patient_illness, substr, 1, 3)
```

Or another option is to convert to `matrix` and do it once

```
patient_illness[] <- substr(as.matrix(patient_illness), 1, 3)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
patient_illness %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ substr(.x, 1, 3)))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. But is there a way I can use for loop to do the same thing? Because I am having trouble in turning a non-for loop code into a for loop to help me iterate the same body codes through the whole tibble. Many thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @hoon99 Yes, you can do `for(i in seq_along(patient_illness)) patient_illness[[i]] <- substr(patient_illness[[i]], 1, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str extract` and the pattern `\\d{3}`, which automatically extracts the first match, i.e., given the pattern, the first three digits in the string:

```
library(tidyverse)
patient_illness %>%
   mutate(across(matches("illness"), ~str_extract(., "\\d{3}")))
```